# extract HTTP POST data (WCF C#)

Tags: c#, http, post

How do i get the data inside an HTTP POST request , that is received in my WCF Service?

i send the data from another service using HTTP POST:

```
        string ReportText = "Hello world";

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(ReportText);

        // Prepare web request...
        String serverURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["REPORT"];
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverURL);
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();

        // Send the data.
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();
```

but when i receive the POST request in the WCF i can't find a way to extract it using WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest,
how do i extract the data from the HTTP POST request ?

Comment: What binding are you using in order to support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in your WCF service?

Comment: Can you post what your service code looks like? It really doesn't look like you're connecting to WCF at all, but rather just making a standard HTTP request.

Comment: @tridus - the client that sends the POST request sends it as a standard HTTP POST, not from a WCF. how can i extract from my WCF the POST data that is sent like the example above ? (Links, code examples...)

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you are using a WCF Rest service and you can pull the GET parameters but you are unable to read RAW post data?

If this is the case then add a Stream parameter to the end of the parameter list in the Contract declaration.  If there is a single stream at the end of the function, the framework treats it as a raw data stream.

```
          [OperationContract]
          [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "DoSomething?siteId={siteId}&configTarget={configTarget}", 
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
          bool DoSomething(string itemid, Stream body);


    public bool DoSomething(int siteId, string configTarget, Stream postData)
    {
        string data = new StreamReader(postData).ReadToEnd();
        return data.Length > 0;
    }
```

See this link for more details:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx

Comment: Thanks James, your post helped me getting my issue fixed. I was trying to create Rest WCF Service which will be requested with content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and the data being posted in request body as 'key=value&key=value.....'. I was struggling a lot to get this structure ready for integrating my application with third party services (which will be calling my service with all these specification)....

Answer (score 0):

`Hello world` isn't exactly `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to encode the post message body accordingly `someproperty=Hello%20world` as well as use WCF HTTP bindings.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't a WCF question, as you're not using WCF. What you're really doing is submitting a form using HTTP Post, and you need to make a web page to receive and handle that. You can do that with the Request.Form collection.

Here's a simple example: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/655226-how-use-request-form